# Spark read file fails with latin1 encoding

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

When I try to read file with  options headers false and encoding latin1... things are working fine. But if i try to read file with headers true and encoding latin1...

getting error like below

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access method com.google.common.base.Stopwatch.<init>()V from class org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:312)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.getPartitions(HadoopRDD.scala:200)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:253)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:251)
```

Line of code to read data without headers.

```
dataset = sparkSession.read()
.option("delimiter", "|")
.option("header", false)
.option("encoding", "ISO-8859-1")
.schema(getDFHeaders())
.csv(inputFilePath)
.toDF();
```

Line of code to read data with headers

```
dataset = sparkSession.read()
.option("delimiter", "|")
.option("header", true)
.option("encoding", "ISO-8859-1")
.csv(inputFilePath)
.toDF();
```

Comment: need sample data  along with header to identify root cause. like this its very difficult to guess issue

Comment: This seems to be conflicting dependency problem of google guava. Which build tool are you using.

Comment: Can you put your build file?